# PHP storing user entered MS Word characters incorrectly into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, diacritics

My web site is generated with PHP and JavaScript and MySQL database. I'm developing and debugging the code with Eclipse Helios.

I'm trying to fix a form which should work correctly when users cut and paste from MicsoSoft Word.

PHP should save the text into MySQL database as entered, and then I want to sanitize it upon retrieval from database.

Retrieving and sanitizing seems to work fine. However, the text stored in the database is sometimes different than what is entered.

For example, when I enter "baño", it gets stored as "baÃ±o"

I stepped thru the code with debugger, and I can see SQL code generated as:

```
insert into table1 set column1 = 'baño'
```

The next step is:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql, $db)) { ...
```

If I then look into the database using phpMyAdmin, or retrieve with PHP, I see the value of column1 as 'baÃ±o'

MySQL uses latin1_swedish_ci as default, and I tried changing it to utf8_unicode_ci, and utf8_bin, but there was no difference.

Similar code works correctly on other databases.

What am I doing wrong?

===================

## ADDED:

This is a big web site with over 100 PHP files and JS files. Database server has 20 databases and in them a few hundred tables.

My problem is only happening in one PHP file and one table. No other code writes into that table, and that files doesn't write into any other table.

Here's the info from phpMyAdmin:

```
MySQL

    Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server version: 5.1.43-log
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost 
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 

Web server

    Apache/2.2.3 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.7b Zend Core/2.0.1 PHP/5.2.1
    MySQL client version: 5.0.27
    PHP extension: mysql 

phpMyAdmin

    Version information: 3.3.7
```

Comment: How are you viewing the stored value?

Comment: Is it set to UTF8 on that individual column?

Comment: Did you try inserting it again after switching it to UTF8?

Comment: character set problem. make sure that your ENTIRE pipeline is utf-8. browser->server->php->mysql->table. every stage has to have same charset, or be joined with appropriate conversion logic. any mismatches, and you end up with what you've got.

Comment: The website has several modules with various databases. No other module has this problem. Only this module writes in this table. So, I'm guessing that the problem is in the table

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET charset_name');
```

before doing the query.

Also, what version of phpMyAdmin are you using?  Look at the header in the HTML source and make sure it's UTF-8.

Comment: I think Marc B's comment is the most complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer. I added more info to the question. Could you tell me how to verify the character set in other parts of the pipeline?

Comment: I added "mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8');" in the line before I do the query, and it works exactly the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

After lots of additional research and experimenting I found this solved my problem:

```
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET "UTF8";',$db);
```

where $db is the resource returned by *mysql_connect()*.